# how does this structure code work

Tags: c, struct, structure, unsigned

Hello all can someone help me with this piece of code

```
struct  
        {  
    unsigned BLOCKDATA:16;  
    unsigned QUALCOUNT:4;  
    unsigned BLOCKTYPE:2;  
    unsigned BE:1;  
    unsigned Z:1;  
    unsigned SYN:1;  
    unsigned DOK:1;  
    unsigned BM:1;  
    unsigned SYNDROME:5;  
}  
    RDSout;
```

I understand that RDSout is a structure and BLOCKDATA and QUALCOUNT etc are the elements of this structure but I dont understand what the **:16** in front of BLOCKDATA means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way you can declare how much bits you want reserved for that variable. It's commonly used to align data structures. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) contains a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers after each element in structure shows how much bits we are reserving for each of them. It is usually done to pack bits and save memory when you already know the exact number of bits to be used. You can also refer [here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/lowlevel_10.htm) to make your concept more clear.

[More Links](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html)

[And One more](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-377882.html)

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot the links were also useful.